# Scheduled task PS script location best practice

Tags: powershell, task-scheduler

Since there isn't a straightforward way to [store and run scripts locally](https://serverfault.com/q/728348/170972) on domain members, I'm resorting to manually store them in a common location across the board and then deploying a task scheduler GPO.

But here's the question: what is the recommended and sensible location?

Comment: Why is storing the script locally not sensible? If it checks network connection status, how else would it run when disconnected? Incidentally, you can deploy files via GPO as well.

Comment: @ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF Ask MDMarra, not me. Precisely because the script is supposed to run in response to network changes I want to store it locally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to recommend that you leverage [Service Management Automation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469260.aspx) for this, rather than have a bunch of scripts in a task scheduler.

Some highlights of SMA include:

- leverages PowerShell workflows for check pointing and job restarts
- Role-based access for who can view what, as well as who can manually kick off jobs
- verbose logging
- Azure-like interface. This is a plus if you already have an investment in Azure.

Comment: 1. This does not answer my question. 2. Doesn't apply to the script I'm trying to run on the domain members.

Comment: @Oxwivi of course it does. Execute the tasks against remote computers from a central location, like SMA. copying scripts to domain members is insanity. What happens when there's a bug and you need to update? You're now copying scripts all over creation and now need a way to track successful copy vs. failure. SMA was meant for what you want.

Comment: ... Did you even read what the script is for in the linked question?